# How to open a PDF document from a local or share drive in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have a Angular 2 application and need a button to open up a PDF document.  This document is on a share drive so I don't think I need to download it.  How can I achieve this in Angular 2 app?  I tried window.open("file://F:\doc1.pdf"); this only opens a new tab in Chrome but nothing is displayed and in IE nothing is happening.

I also try using anchor tag (see below) in the html but still no luck.   I can paste this link in a browser and it will bring up the doc.

```html
<a href="file://F:\Dock1.pdf" target="_blank">Doc1</a>
```